# Adding Emojis to server with discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to create a website for discord emojis, and I got an idea to make the bot put emoji on the server. Now I did not find any help on youtube so I am here to ask. Hope I get some help

Comment: YouTube isn't the only place. Search Google, search StackOverflow, join their official discord server, ask there, read the documentation, use the search feature inside the documentation. if all fails ask here

Comment: Also consider providing more details like where you get the emoji from and such

Comment: I get emoji from my desktop.

Comment: It might be a good idea to try something yourself using [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji) and updating this question if you encounter an error you cannot solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With the vague details you said, I've come up with this

```py
@client.command()
async def add_emoji(ctx)
    emoji_path = ""  # put your desired file path to get the emoji from
    with open(emoji_path, "rb") as f:
        await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name="emoji_name", image=f.read())
```

This opens the emoji in both [read mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open:%7E:text=open%20for%20reading%20(default)) and [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open:%7E:text=b%27-,binary%20mode,-%27t) using `'rb'`. So it can read the raw bytes of the image since [Guild.create_custom_emoji only takes bytes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji:%7E:text=image%20(bytes)%20%E2%80%93%20the%20bytes-like%20object%20representing%20the%20image%20data%20to%20use.%20only%20jpg%2C%20png%20and%20gif%20images%20are%20supported.) and then passes that raw bytes and a name to [uild.create_custom_emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_custom_emoji)